# Spark (1.6) ML Linear Regression - how to predict w/ a model

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have a working linear regression model:

```
lrModel
org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel
```

and I have data in a dataframe:

```
data
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [label: double, features: vector]
```

How do I use the model to predict?  in my case, I want to do something like:

```
lrModel.predict(data)  // which doesn't work
```

then compare the expected value (label) to the predicted value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To predict you need to have a `Dataframe`, and convert it using the [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=linearregression#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel.transform) method which is part of all  [ML Models](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.Model). Note that all of them require `DataFrame`s to have the same structure of your training data, hence a `fetures` column.